# Downside of using TransactionScope RequiresNew

Tags: c#, .net, sql, entity-framework

I want to understand what is the trade-of/downside of using `TransactionScopeOption.RequiresNew` on **EntityFramework** (**w/ Sql Server 2008**), what are the reasons why we should NOT use `RequiresNew` always.

Regards.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You should use `Required` not `RequiresNew`. RequiresNew means every operation will use a new transaction, even if there is an encompassing already existing transaction scope. This will certainly lead to deadlocks. Even with `Required` there is another serious problem with `TransactionScope`, namely that it creates by default a `Serializable` transaction, which is a horribly bad choice and yet another shortcut to deadlock hell and no scalability. See [using new TransactionScope() Considered Harmful](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dbrowne/archive/2010/05/21/using-new-transactionscope-considered-harmful.aspx). You should always create a transaction scope with the explicit `TransactionOption` setting the isolation level to `ReadCommitted`, which a much much much more sane isolation level:

```
using(TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope(
    TransactionScopeOption.Required,
    new TransactionOptions {
       IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted}))
{
   /// do work here
   ...
   scope.Complete();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  Then when should we used RequiresNew?

Comment: `RequiresNew` is to be used when you want a standalone transaction, not part of the calling  context transaction. In other words **never**.

Comment: Sometimes `RequiresNew` is useful for logging or auditing that should succeed regardless of the encompasing transaction. I agree, consider carefully before using.

Comment: @BrianLow: But unless your logging/auditing code uses `IEnlistmentNotification` wouldn't it always log and never roll back if the outer transaction fails?

Comment: `RequiresNew` shouldn't be used to isolate logging/auditing from potentially aborting a transaction if say the logging code threw an exception, that's what `TransactionScope.Suppress` is designed explicitly for.

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add here that in a couple certain cases the method i've written is inside a parent transaction scope that may or may not be closed with `scope.Complete()` in these cases I didn't want to be dependent on the parent transaction so we needed to set RequiresNew.

In general though I agree it's not necessary and should use read committed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152(v=vs.90).aspx