# What is the difference between nesting a Transaction with the default Required option, and not doing it all?

Tags: c#, transactionscope

I've seen examples of code where a TransactionScope is nested inside another like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx)

```
using(TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
     try
     {
          //Start of non-transactional section 
          using(TransactionScope scope2 = new
             TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
          {
               //Do non-transactional work here
          }
          //Restores ambient transaction here
   }
     catch
     {}
   //Rest of scope1
}
```

I can understand here the use of `Supress` but as far as I understand `Required` just merges with the outer Transaction, so that if anything fails, the whole thing fails, so what's the point? Am I missing something here?

**EDIT:** 
Just to be clear I want to emphasize that the Suppress option I (think I :-)) understand, which is explained in the MSDN documentation. My question is on the default **Required** option; maybe I don't fully understand but if Transaction B is nested inside Transaction A then if either A fails **or** B fails then both A **and** B will be rolled back, which is the same if I never put B in a transaction in the first place.

So the question reworded is '*What is the difference between nesting a Transaction with the default Required option, and not doing it all?*'

Comment: have you read the MSDN example and explanation on [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)

Comment: @DJKRAZE if I am quoting the MSDN page with a back link included, then  most probably yes.

Answer (score 0):

Think about this:

```
using(TransactionScope scope1 = new TransactionScope())
{
     //i insert some records in tabe A
     try
     {              
          using(TransactionScope scope2 = new
             TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
          {                  
               // I insert some records in table B
               scope2.Complete() 
          }
          //I insert some records in table C
   }
     catch
     {}
   //I Update some records in table D
   //I Delete some records of table E
   // Here we have an exception being thrown                       
 scope1.Complete() 
}
```

after running the code 
**all changes to tables A,C,D,E will be rolled back** 
**all changes to table B will be committed**

[TrnsactionScop Down side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760570/downside-of-using-transactionscope-requiresnew)

Comment: B runs without any transaction. There is no transaction there to be committed. The statement about a c d and f is correct (given that there is no `scope1.Complete()` call). Hint you mention B, but it is nowhere in your code.

Comment: my question was regarding the default Required option, not the Suppress. I'm going to edit my question to make this more clear.