# Need help to use transaction scope

Tags: c#, sql-server, deadlock, transactionscope, isolation-level

I am working on analaysis and preventive measure for deadlock in application, Where I found following line of code for transaction scope:

```
var tranaction = new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted };

// TransactionScopeOption.Required changed to Suppress for 2 tier issue with MSDTC
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress, tranaction))
{
   //Select entity command.
}
```

We are only having some `select` entity statement which will allow dirty read operations.
I have read some resources on `TransactionScopeOption` but here I don't find exact `TransactionScopeOption` in this case or feel like we can change option to `RequiredNew` and let's create new transaction every time when select command executed. Need help to move forward. We are using SQL Server as datasource. If we change it to `RequiredNew` then what will be the performance impact since this change will be done for all select entity command in application?

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: @WicherVisser Can `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress` change to `TransactionScopeOption.RequiredNew`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to allow `IsolationLevel` to be `ReadUncommitted`, then you shouldn't use `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress`.

Usage of `TransactionScopeOption.Suppress` will not take part in any `Transaction` and the `IsolationLevel` always defaults to the Database default which is `IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted` in SQL server.

You need to either join with an `Ambient` transaction or create a new transaction to `IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted`.

So you can definitely change to `TransactionScopeOption.RequiredNew` to allow dirty reads if that's what you want.

**EDIT**
Short Answer: In a way

Long Answer:
Escalation to MS DTC is the result of having more than one connections to DB in a single `TransactionScope`.

Different versions of SQL Server handles this escalation in different ways,
`SQL Server 2008` will not escalate unless both connections are open at the same time whereas previous version will always escalate on multiple connections.

Make sure you don't have multiple connections in a single `TransactionScope` and you should be alright. But by seeing your code, you already have multiple connections opened and MS DTC escalations are created.

Using `RequiresNew` means creating a new `TransactionScope` always, even if this encompassed in `Ambient` Scope.  This will almost always creates deadlocks and timeout issues if not properly handled. Your best option here is to change the way you're accessing the `DB` to more proven recommended patterns to avoid issues.

Comment: Does [`Microsoft Distributed Transaction Coordinator`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Distributed_Transaction_Coordinator) do play any role in it?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar Added my thoughts to answer

Comment: Can you give your thoughts on performance if we do change transaction scope to `RequiredNew`.. Since this change will done for all call where having select entity command in whole application.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure I understand your question.

If you mean to ask if - programmatically - you can use the `RequiredNew` scope option for your transaction scope, then yes, this is possible:

[image]

Does it makes sense to use `RequiredNew`? Most likely not, as it creates a transaction scope **always** for each transaction, rather than re-using scopes. The drawback is mentioned in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760570/downside-of-using-transactionscope-requiresnew).